# Pandas data conversion

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data in a Pandas dataframe:

```
AIRPORT
EWR|JAX
EWR|BHX
EWR|BHX
EWR|BHX
EWR|BHX
```

...
Is there a dynamic way to convert this to:

```
AIRPORT  EWR JAX BHX
EWR|JAX  Y   Y   NULL
EWR|BHX  Y   NULL Y
```

and so on. I know how to do this if I want to count the hard coded values

```
 df.assign(EWR = lambda x: x.TYPE.apply(lambda y: y.split('|').count('EWR')))
```

but I'm hoping not to have to write this code for each airport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`pandas` only with `str.get_dummies`**

```
dummies = df.AIRPORT.str.get_dummies()
df.join(
    dummies * pd.Series('Y', dummies.columns)
).replace('', np.nan)

   AIRPORT  BHX EWR  JAX
0  EWR|JAX  nan   Y    Y
1  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  nan
2  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  nan
3  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  nan
4  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  nan
```

**`pandas` & `numpy` with `np.where`**

```
dummies = df.AIRPORT.str.get_dummies()
d1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(dummies.values == 1, 'Y', np.nan),
    dummies.index, dummies.columns
)
d2 = df.join(d1)
print(d2)

   AIRPORT  BHX EWR  JAX
0  EWR|JAX  nan   Y    Y
1  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  nan
2  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  nan
3  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  nan
4  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  nan
```

---

**Timing**
*small data*

```
%%timeit
df.join(
    df.AIRPORT.str.get_dummies() * pd.Series('Y', dummies.columns)
).replace('', np.nan)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.31 ms per loop

%timeit df.assign(**df.AIRPORT.str.get_dummies().replace({1:'Y',0:np.nan}))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop

%%timeit
dummies = df.AIRPORT.str.get_dummies()
d1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(dummies.values == 1, 'Y', np.nan),
    dummies.index, dummies.columns
)
df.join(d1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 ms per loop
```

*large data*

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

np.random.seed([3,1415])
source = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(list(ascii_uppercase), [100, 3])
).sum(1).unique()
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(source, [10000, 2]), columns=['A', 'B']
).query('A != B').apply('|'.join, 1).to_frame('AIRPORT')

%%timeit
dummies = df.AIRPORT.str.get_dummies()
df.join(
    dummies * pd.Series('Y', dummies.columns)
).replace('', np.nan)
1 loop, best of 3: 594 ms per loop

%timeit df.assign(**df.AIRPORT.str.get_dummies().replace({1:'Y',0:np.nan}))
1 loop, best of 3: 629 ms per loop

%%timeit
dummies = df.AIRPORT.str.get_dummies()
d1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(dummies.values == 1, 'Y', np.nan),
    dummies.index, dummies.columns
)
df.join(d1)
1 loop, best of 3: 592 ms per loop
```

Comment: My dataset is somewhat large and using query helps. str.get_dummies() rules

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.str` accessor and `get_dummies`, then using `assign` with dictionary unpacking to create the additional columns in your dataframe. And, lastly `replace` to change those 0's and 1's to your str, bool, and nan of choice.

```
df_out = df.assign(**df.AIRPORT.str.get_dummies().replace({1:'Y',0:np.nan}))
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   AIRPORT  BHX EWR  JAX
0  EWR|JAX  NaN   Y    Y
1  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  NaN
2  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  NaN
3  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  NaN
4  EWR|BHX    Y   Y  NaN
```

Comment: You know I like the use of `assign` :-)... and `replace` is a nice touch.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.